# Jquery Accordion Menu - Stay open when navigating to a new page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, model-view-controller

I have an MVC project which uses a JQuery Accordion Menu for navigation. I am wondering if there is any way to modify the menu so that when I click one of the links, the menu stays open when it navigates to the next page

jQuery -

```
$(document).ready(function () {


    //ACCORDION BUTTON ACTION

    $('div.accordionButton').click(function () {

        //IF THE DIV YOU CLICKED IS ALREADY OPEN, CLOSE AND REMOVE THE OPEN CLASS

        if ($(this).next().hasClass('openDiv')) {

            $('div.accordionContent.openDiv').slideUp('normal');

            $('div.accordionContent.openDiv').removeClass('openDiv');

        }

            //CLOSE ANY OPEN DIVS, OPEN THE CLICKED DIV

        else {

            $('div.accordionContent.openDiv').slideUp('normal');

            $('div.accordionContent.openDiv').removeClass('openDiv');

            $(this).next().slideDown('normal');

            $(this).next().addClass('openDiv');

        }

    });

    //HIDE THE DIVS ON PAGE LOAD

    $("div.accordionContent").hide();

});
```

HTML -

```
@foreach (var sport in Model.SportTypesList)
    {
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div class="accordionButton">@sport.ToString()</div>
            <div class="accordionContent">
                @foreach (var coupon in Model.CurrentCoupons())
                {
                    if (coupon.SportID.ToString().Equals(sport.ToString()))
                    {
                        <div id="bullets">></div>
                        @Ajax.ActionLink(@coupon.CouponName, "Index", "Home", new { couponName = coupon.CouponName, sportName = coupon.SportID.ToString() }, new AjaxOptions
                        {
                            UpdateTargetId = "coupons",
                            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                            HttpMethod = "GET"
                        })
                        <br />
                    }
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    }
```

Comment: You can look into various stateful solutions here.  1. via the server 2. via a cookie 3 via localStorage.  Implementation of each is slightly different.  With 1 you'll have to set a class or javascript variable to be read and acted upon on new page load, with 2 & 3 you'll have to query the cookie/storage and act on new page load too.

Answer (score 0):

You can put in the session the id of the tab you selected and from there just check the id and keep open the tab. One easy solution.